# How to get number of pixels between two points : leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, pixel, polyline

I am working with the simple app which is using leaflet plugins....

I want to get the number of pixels when i draw a poly-line on map(from one point to another using poly-lines)....

Actually i don't have idea how to bound the required events....(having so low knowledge and experience in jquery)

[Using This](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-draw/)
(please consider i am using as it is, this example)

I have tried searches but didn't found anything related to this, please if someone help

Any kind of help or reference will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea how to do it in leaflet. It would require the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) It would look like this in js: `distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x1-x2, 2 ) + Math.pow(y1-y2, 2 ));`

Comment: What do you mean by number of pixels? The distance between 2 points?

Comment: Many browsers now support the `Math.hypot()` function that takes the x and y distance and returns the hypotenuse thus `var distance = Math.hypot(x1-x2,y1-y2);` it is a lot faster than using `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2,2)+Math.pow(y1-y2,2))`

Comment: @miro thanks for reply, i was asking how can i get distance between two poly-line points in "pixel" or whatever,,,, right now i am focusing on only to get the distance of two poly-line points....as it appears on popup, i just want to use that value in my javascript function

Comment: @RafZeres thanks for reply, i am willing to know the function which will give the distance between two point as we see in popup of any shape on leaflet draw .... was actually asking to get that distance in pixels

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks for information man